# Reducing the length of my SQL code

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am using a third party software for this SQL query which has various limitations, one being a character limit of 1,000 characters. I have created code that will pull through a list of contact numbers registered to a particular account, and have had a view created specifically for this task. My current script (see below) works, but brings back duplicate responses. I want to shorten the length of the code, and to select for only Distinct responses.

As background, the CRM system this is linked to has multiple places someone can leave a contact number, so I need the code to remove any duplicates when it displays the response. The current code does not attempt to remove duplicates due to the aforementioned character limit, it is:

```
SELECT [Contact_Mobile_Phone] AS V, [Contact_Mobile_Phone] AS D
FROM [DatabaseName]
WHERE MAINLKUPID = '{Import.TenantID}' AND [Contact_Mobile_Phone] IS NOT NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT [Contact_Home_Phone] AS V, [Contact_Home_Phone] AS D
FROM [DatabaseName]
WHERE MAINLKUPID = '{Import.TenantID}' AND [Contact_Home_Phone] IS NOT NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT [Contact_Work_Phone] AS V, [Contact_Work_Phone] AS D
FROM [DatabaseName]
WHERE MAINLKUPID = '{Import.TenantID}' AND [Contact_Work_Phone] IS NOT NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT [Group_Home_Phone] AS V, [Group_Home_Phone] AS D
FROM [DatabaseName]
WHERE MAINLKUPID = '{Import.TenantID}' AND [Group_Home_Phone] IS NOT NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT [Group_Mobile_Phone] AS V, [Group_Mobile_Phone] AS D
FROM [DatabaseName]
WHERE MAINLKUPID = '{Import.TenantID}' AND [Group_Mobile_Phone] IS NOT NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT [Contact_Home_Phone] AS V, [Contact_Home_Phone] AS D
FROM [DatabaseName]
WHERE [Group_ID] = '{Script.V1}' AND [Contact_Home_Phone] IS NOT NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT [Contact_Mobile_Phone] AS V, [Contact_Mobile_Phone] AS D
FROM [DatabaseName]
WHERE [Group_ID] = '{Script.V1}' AND [Contact_Mobile_Phone] IS NOT NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Enter other number' AS V, 'Enter other number' AS D
```

As you can see, it's not the most elegant thing I've coded. What I want it to look like, is something similar to this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ([Contact_Mobile_Phone], [Contact_Home_Phone], [Contact_Work_Phone], [Group_Home_Phone], [Group_Mobile_Phone]) V,
([Contact_Mobile_Phone], [Contact_Home_Phone], [Contact_Work_Phone], [Group_Home_Phone], [Group_Mobile_Phone]) D
FROM [DatabaseName]
WHERE MAINLKUPID = '{Import.TenantID}' AND ([Contact_Mobile_Phone], [Contact_Home_Phone], [Contact_Work_Phone], [Group_Home_Phone], [Group_Mobile_Phone])  IS NOT NULL
AND MAINLKUPID = '{Import.TenantID}' AND ([Contact_Mobile_Phone], [Contact_Home_Phone], [Contact_Work_Phone], [Group_Home_Phone], [Group_Mobile_Phone])  IS NOT NULL
```

The criteria is that it needs to display the same results in both Column V and D. It needs to not pull through Null data, and it needs to only enter each number once into each column, even if they came from different columns originally. I'm aware the syntax for my ideal code isn't right, hoping someone can point me in the right direction. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Removing the duplicates is a simple matter of changing the `union all`s to `union`s.

Comment: I have read this several times and each time I read it I am more confused by what you actually want here. But as @DanBracuk already mentioned removing the duplicates is easy.

Comment: Can you add sample data, and show us the output you would expect?

Comment: Thanks all. I can't believe I didn't spot that! Thank you @DanBracuk, that has solved the duplicates issue. I'm still wondering if there is a way I can simplify the query in how it's written

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you put the code in a stored procedure and just call "EXEC my_stored_procedure;"? That would be a lot shorter!

Comment: I agree! However I do not have access to do this, I only have access to this limited third party software. Our IT department are also a very stretched resource currently, so trying to find the best solution that I can implement to help them out

Answer (score 0):

Can you explain why you are selecting the same column twice, but giving it different names?  Perhaps you intend for the first to be a description.  If so, it should be in single quotes not square braces -- but this will affect the duplicate elimination.

You can do the following to remove duplicates:

- Replace the `UNION ALL` with `UNION`

You can do the following to reduce the size:

- Remove all square braces
- Remove `as V` and `as D` from all but the first query

If that is not short enough, then remove the `NULL` comparison and structure the query as:

```
select *
from (<your query here with no null comparisons and `union` instead of `union all`) x
where d is not null;
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice. The third party software I am using needs to have a display field, and a value filed, hence V and D. The display field will show the end user what numbers are available to select, the system then uses the value field to take the selected data forwards into the rest of the script. I hope that made sense.

Comment: @CraigJones can you move the column duplication out of each `select` into an outer `select`: `select N as V, N as D from ( select [Contact_Mobile_Phone] as N from ... union ... ) as X`?

Answer (score 0):

```
select  phone_num as V,phone_num as D
from    [DatabaseName] unpivot (phone_num for phone_type in ([Contact_Mobile_Phone],[Contact_Home_Phone],[Contact_Work_Phone],[Group_Home_Phone],[Group_Mobile_Phone])) u
where   MAINLKUPID = '{Import.TenantID}'
union
select  phone_num as V,phone_num as D
from    [DatabaseName] unpivot (phone_num for phone_type in ([Contact_Home_Phone],[Contact_Mobile_Phone])) u
WHERE   [Group_ID] = '{Script.V1}'
union all
SELECT 'Enter other number','Enter other number'
```